# How to implement full-screen mode?

Tags: windows, user-interface

How full-screen mode, like in web browsers, for application running under Windows OS  is implemented? Is it more complex then maximizing a window and hiding window decoration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form Style = NONE, maximized.

If you specify the language you could probably get some sample code.

---

**EDIT**: in response to what [Greg posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437352/how-to-implement-full-screen-mode#437437), this will work in .Net for sure, not sure about other languages.

Comment: Got it.

But I guess there should be an extra step of bringing the application on top of all other windows and task bar, shouldn't it? At least IE seems to work that way and it sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: it actually does it automatically (windows), any window class without a windows border style that is maximized will go over all "explorer" windows.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not more complicated than what you propose. I know of one example of such code in the [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) viewer source, since I contributed the first implementation of that very feature many years ago.

Comment: This should be a comment, not a new post, but... In .Net you simply set the FormBorderStyle = None and WindowState = Maximized and it will go into "kiosk" mode.  I have about 10 apps running like this on touch screen terminals.

Comment: Yeah, the original question is unclear on the exact platform. I assumed bare Win32 API.